How to wrap HTML around a block in django?
Similar to this question which didn't have an answer that works for me. I'm trying to customise allauth templates:

email.html extends base_manage_email.html
base_manage_email.html extends base_manage.html
base_manage.html extends manage.html which I've overidden to extend my base layout.

I want to wrap content as follows in base_manage.html:
{% extends "allauth/layouts/manage.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="format">
    {{ block.super }}
</div>
{% endblock %}


This doesn't work though because I actually need something like {{ block.child }} to wrap where the child content (email.html) will be included. What actually happens is the contents of email.html is directly rendered as in my base.html.
How can I simply add default formatting to all the allauth templates that extend base_manage.html?

Wouldn't a solution be to just make a copy of the manage.html and do it correct there. Yes, I know that is not very "clean", but as far as I know, you can make some sort of "mixin" block, well probably you can with a custom template tag, but that is currently not available.

But it's the same problem. There's no way to refer to the contents of a child block AFAIK. My manage.html extends my base.html template which is used for the whole site.

no, what I mean is you duplicate manage.html, but you define a {% block content %} inside the <div class="format">.

I'm not sure I understand. Won't that only work if manage.html is a base layout? Otherwise how will my base layout know that that extra HTML should be inserted into my content block?

yes, the point is to clone the root template, and there alter it such that content is wrapped in the <div>.

Yeah that's why I'm asking this question, to avoid something like that.

In the end I've gone with this in my base layout, but would like to see any better solutions:
<div class="space-y-4 
   {% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'account_email' or 
     request.resolver_match.url_name == 'account_change_password' or 
     request.resolver_match.url_name == 'account_logout' %}format{% endif %}">
   {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>

